# Incrementing a where value in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a rollup table and because of size I need to run it by each year from 2002 through 2017.  I can run this as a query or stored procedure, doesn't matter.

I know there is a way to cycle through each query changing the year.

Any help is appreciated.

```
insert into rollup_rb_period_earnings(account_name,song_title,deal_id,period,total_amount)
select account_name, song_title,deal_id,period_year_quarter,SUM(royalty_amount)
FROM royalty_stream
WHERE period_year = 2002
GROUP BY  account_name, song_title,deal_id,period_year_quarter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just fix the `where` clause to have the years that you need:

```
insert into rollup_rb_period_earnings(account_name, song_title, deal_id, period, total_amount)
    select account_name, song_title, deal_id, period_year_quarter, sum(royalty_amount)
    from royalty_stream
    where period_year between 2002 and 2017
    group by account_name, song_title, deal_id, period_year_quarter;
```

Comment: No, I need each to be a separate query.  The table is too large to run just one query, I have to split it up into separate statements.

Comment: @SeanPeace . . . That sounds ridiculous to me.  How large is the table?

Comment: I would not be asking if I had not already tried and failed with such a simple where clause.  The royalty_stream table is 75G with 193,885,384 rows.  The server has 20G memory. I had to cut the query into chunks manually because one query fails.  The rollup table alone is 4.7G.

Comment: The `group by` should not be a big load on memory.  It uses file storage for the intermediate table.  Is it possible to expand the temporary space available to MySQL?

Comment: The disk has plenty of space, not sure if you are saying that is a parameter I need to set?